# Edit jump lists of certain shortcuts?

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts

After updating Windows 10 a few days ago, MS Edge's taskbar shortcut started to not work properly anymore:

1. Somehow the update turned the new icon (right) back to the old icon (left), and
2. whenever I click on the launcher icon (left) a separate icon for the window appears (right).

[image: Improperly working icon (left) and instance icon (right)]

I fixed this issue by creating a custom shortcut to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe`, but this introduced a new problem: The jumplist of the newly created shortcut is missing the jumplist entries for *opening a new window* and *opening a new private window*.

[image: Proper jumplist (left) and missing jumplist entries (right)]

My question now is whether it is possible to either change the left shortcut's icon back to the new icon (and make it not spawn new taskbar icons) or to add jumplist entries to the right shortcut?

Comment: Have you already tried Shift + right click on that icon (the left), then Properties? It should open the properties window and allow to change the path.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and at the same time right-click on the icon you wish to change.
2. On the context menu that appears, select Properties.
3. Set the "Target" and "Start in" folder.
4. If necessary, click on Change Icon, select the icon you want. Click OK. Click OK.

Comment: The "properties" entry seems to only be present on manually created shortcuts. The improperly working icon only has "Open", "Detach from Start", "Detach from taskbar" and "Create shortcut". (And yes, I held down Shift)

Comment: @Cubi73 if Edge is open, try to close it (and any of its iopened nstances). Then try again to see of context menu appears or not.

Comment: I did: https://imgur.com/a/hI9kazT The entries are those listed in my previous comment.

Comment: The improperly working shortcut was added to the taskbar by searching for "Edge" via Win+S and then right-clicking + "add to taskbar". I can't even find a shortcut file of this shortcut.

Comment: @Cubi73 Strange that yours does not show it. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5Hr7.png) is shown when I right-click, and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSB0N.png) when I press shift+right-click. Need to find out where the shortcuts are stored then.

Comment: @Cubi73 If you go to `%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`, is the icon present?

Comment: I can find an Edge shortcut in the Admin's TaskBar folder, but not in the user's TaskBar folder, which is strange, because the user should have pinned Edge to the taskbar, but the Admin should not.

Comment: @Cubi73 Maybe you will have to unpin ut. But it may mean that the jump lists will be lost.

Comment: Okay, I just unpinned all the Edge shortcuts, removed the Edge shortcuts I created myself entirely from `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`, moved the Edge shortcut from `C:\Users\Dennis\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch` (which I didn't create) to the `Programs` folder and pinned this icon to the taskbar. Now, the shortcut has the new icon and the jumplist entries, but it still spawns new icons when opening Edge.

Comment: @Cubi73 Maybe try to unpin any Edge icon from the task, this should remove it. Open Edge, then pin it. Now, see if the newly pin shortcut/icon will have the same issue.

Comment: If I unpin all Edge shortcuts, then open Edge and pin the instance to the taskbar, the shortcut will not spawn new icons upon launching Edge,  but it is missing the jump list entries.

Comment: Well, I think I'm gonna live with the shortcut spawning new icons. At least the shortcut has the jumplist entries which I use quite frequently.

Comment: @Cubi73 With time (and usage), the jump list should be re-populated.

Comment: That might hold true for frequently used websites, but probably not for "hardcoded" entries like opening a new private window